# Navigation controller issue

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar along with navigation controller iphone application. Now I need another MainView before this tab bar view is shown..please help me in doing so.

When i use navigationController for the MainView and display it using

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
```

instead of earlier used

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

then i get the MainView, but in other views the tabbars are not shown. The navigation to other view is done through button on this MainView
Could any one explain me how would i get this done..i.e. a main view (without tab bar) and the next views all be with tab bars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App Delegate Method add MAinView in Navigation Controller and then add to window:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
   MainView *objMV = [[[MainView alloc]init] autorelease];
   UINavigationController *mainNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:m_objMV];
   [self.window addSubview:mainNavController.view];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
 }
```

Now button's click event which is present in MainView  its method is below:

```
 -(IBAction)yourBtnAction:(id)sender
{
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
  [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.window cache:NO];
  [UIView commitAnimations];

  [mainNavController.view removeFromSuperview];
  [m_mainNavController release];

   // Your tab bar controller instance ie tabBarController 

  [self.window addSubview:tabBarController];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 }
```

Comment: thanks safecase..but sorry to ask how do i get access of  mainNavController in my MainView button's click event. Being a newbie here I dont know how things work

Comment: using self.navigationController if navigation Controller has mainView ether wise value will be nil